# how schedule a batch job to run at different times

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I have a requirement where batch job should be scheduled every day from at different times, meaning first day it should be scheduled at 9:00 A.M in the morning. When it reschedules itself the next day it should schedule itself at 10:00 A.M. When the schedule time reaches 8:00 P.M, for the next day it should schedule itself to again back to 9:00 A.M in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by **rescheduling the batch in finish method** of your batch. You can store information for which time batch is running in batch. When your batch complete, then in finish method you can check for which time that batch was running and reschedule batch again with different time.